# Disable eslint Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I'm trying to complete a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpOaE0sW6qU&list=PLWd_VnthxxLeRdaga093nbR64dALpbPwI&index=8).

I'm stuck with an error that is caused by ESLint:

```
> Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\romul\Vue Projects\produto-client\src\App.vue
  110:36  error  'resposta' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

I want to know how to disable eslint.

This is my project structure:

[image]

I searched on the internet, but I couldn't understand how to disable it.

Comment: Why not just remove the unused vars? And is this VS Code?

Comment: you can disable this rule in the config

Comment: Yes i´m using vs code, i'm just trying to follow the tutorial and this is how he ask to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *correct* solution to your problem is to actually follow the linter error and remove the unused variables from your code, either temporarily comment them out or delete the line entirely. Disabling the linter is a temporary workaround, but should not be a long-term solution.

But, for the purposes of your question, it is possible to disable the linter (ESLint).

When creating the standard Vue app directory, you have the option of enabling ESLint and storing the ESLint configuration in either the *package.json* or in a separate *.eslintrc.js* file. From your screenshot, it seems you added the ESLint configuration in your *package.json*, like this:

[image]

See that `eslintConfig` block?

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
```

You can enable/disable specific [ESLint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) in the `rules` block.
For example, for [`no-unused-vars`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars):

```
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
```

Then make changes to the *src* files and save (the default Vue configuration is to [run the linter on save](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#lintonsave)).

If the ESLint rules are in a separate *.eslintrc.js* file, the procedure is the same, just on/off specific rules under the `rules` block.

Or, if you want to disable ESLint entirely, create a [*vue.config.js*](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) file with the [`lintOnSave`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#lintonsave) setting set to `false`:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    lintOnSave: false
}
```

Now, running the app (`npm run serve`) won't anymore trigger the linter.

Additionally, if you are using VS Code, it supports [ESLint integration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/vuejs-tutorial#_linting). I'm not sure if the rest of your tutorial will also discuss linting with VS Code, but it can/might also report some errors/warnings in the Problems tab.

You can disable them from your User/Workspace settings:

```
"eslint.enable": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

several ways to do this:

- create a `.eslintignore` file at the root of your project, and input `**/*`. this will ignore all files in your project

OR

- create a `.eslintrc.json` file at the root of your project. and input

```
{
  "rules":{
  "no-unused-vars": "off"
 }
}
```

this will suppress the specific error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to set the `lintOnSave: false` in your vue.config.js file.

This simply stops the eslint-loader running when the file is compiled.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false
}
```

The better solution is to set `lineOnSave: 'warning'` which ensures that eslint errors are emitted as warnings therefore the errors aren't surpressed but they also don't prevent the compiling.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: 'warning'
}
```

See documentation here: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#lintonsave